# Call java method on primefaces treeTable columns reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

For Primefaces [treeTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf) component i ve added jquery ui droppable and draggable events so i can reorder columns.

**tree.xhtml**

```xhtml
<p:treeTable id="items" var="item" value="#{bean.root}" >   
  <c:forEach var="column" items="#{bean.columns}" style="width:70px;">
    <p:column headerText="#{column.header}">
      <h:outputText value="#{some data}" />
    </p:column>
  </c:forEach>                    
</p:treeTable>
```

**tree.js**

```js
$('.ui-resizable-column')
    .draggable(
    {
        appendTo : 'body',
        opacity : '0.6',
        cursor : 'pointer',
        scope : this.id,
    })
    .droppable(
    {
        drop : function(g, h) {
            .. implementation goes here...
            $.ajax().done(function(){
                alert( 'done!' );
            });
        }
    });
```

As a result I want to keep track of column order so I need an ajax event for this or any other remote method invocation back on Java back-end. How can I call function on a back end like. Is it possible with JS or primefaces?

```
public void reOrder( BehaviorEvent event ){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - on jquery event completion make call to remoteCommand which will execute bean method.

**tree.xhtml**

```
$.ajax().done(function(){
   callToBean();
});
```

**tree.js**

```
<p:remoteCommand name="callToBean" actionListener="#{bean.reOrder/>
```